# Path counting discrete

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I need help understanding a simple concept. Lets say you're given a problem where you start at (0,0) on a 2D grid and want to count the number of paths to (8,4). Would I be following the combinations problem where (m,n) = (m + n) choose m? And would this be the same as (m + n) choose n? To build off that problem, lets say I'm not able to move through (3,2) to (4,2). Would this mean that I would solve the same problem (12 choose 8) - (5 choose 3) because I don't want to move right at the point (3,2)? Thanks guys!

Comment: $\displaystyle{m+n \choose m}= {m+n \choose n}$ since they are both equal to $\dfrac{(m+n)!}{m!\, n!} $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you’re allowed only to move one unit to the right or one unit up, then you must take a total of $m$ steps to the right and $n$ up to get from $\langle 0,0\rangle$ to $\langle m,n\rangle$. You can take those steps in any order and still reach your destination, so the $m$ steps to the right can occupy any $m$ positions in the string of $m+n$ steps. Thus, there are indeed $\binom{m+n}m=\binom{m+n}n$ possible paths using only these two types of step. In particular, there are $\binom{12}8$ such paths from the origin to $\langle 8,4\rangle$.

If you’re not permitted to take the step from $\langle 3,2\rangle$ to $\langle 4,2\rangle$, you must subtract from $\binom{12}8$ the number of paths that use this step. Each of those paths consists of a path from the origin to $\langle 3,2\rangle$, the forbidden step, and a path from $\langle 4,2\rangle$ to $\langle 8,4\rangle$. There are $\binom53$ paths from the origin to $\langle 3,2\rangle$. Getting from $\langle 4,2\rangle$ to $\langle 8,4\rangle$ requires $8-4=4$ steps to the right and $4-2=2$ steps up, so there are $\binom{4+2}4=\binom62$ such paths. Each of them can be combined with any of the $\binom53$ paths from the origin to $\langle 3,2\rangle$ to make a forbidden path, so there are altogether $\binom53\binom64$ forbidden paths and $$\binom{12}8-\binom53\binom64=495-10\cdot15=345$$ acceptable paths.

Comment: @user2933041: You’re welcome.